# Select layer by location in ArcPy ERROR 000368

Tags: arcpy, layers, select-by-location, error-000368

I am trying to create a scrip that create a list of all features in my GDB, then select objects that intersect with a user given shapefile, and finally copy selected features to a new location. After I have successfully created a list with features within my GDB, I am having troubles selecting objects that intersect with the shapefile provided by the user.

My code looks like this:

```
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy import env

nuevaAOI = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

pathBase = r"C:\Users\SCGEO\Documents\SIANCERO\InfoTematicaEIA.gdb"
arcpy.env.workspace = pathBase    

featureDataSets = arcpy.ListDatasets(feature_type='feature')    

featureClasses = []
    
for fds in featureDataSets:
    for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_dataset=fds):
        featureClasses.append(os.path.join(pathBase, fds, fc))    

for f in featureClasses:
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(f,"INTERSECT", nuevaAOI, 2000, "NEW_SELECTION")
```

After I run the code an error message is prompt stating:

```
"Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000368: Invalid input data.
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByLocation)."
```

Can anybody give me a hint on this?

Comment: All Layer operators need a `Layer` argument (feature class path would not preserve the selection). Note that you won't capture any feature classes that aren't in feature datasets with the code above (which should generally be most of them).

Comment: Thanks Vince. I see the error now

Answer (score 1):

As the error message said, the parameters are not valid.  And as @Vince commented, the particular parameter that is invalid is the first one, the layer.  To see what parameters are valid, check the documentation at:  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-location.htm

The first parameter should be a feature layer not a feature class.

You can create a layer from a feature class in ArcPy like this:

```py
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(featureClass, layer)
```

To incorporate this into your code, you could do something like:

```
for f in featureClasses:
    lyr = os.path.basename(f + "_layer")  #  This can be any text you like - just a layer name
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(f, lyr)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(lyr,"INTERSECT", nuevaAOI, 2000, "NEW_SELECTION")
    # DO SOMETHING WITH THE LAYER HERE
    arcpy.Delete_management(lyr)  #  Does not delete the feature class, only the layer that points to it - like removing the layer from ArcMap
```